# Coredata index insert directly in the sqlite file

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, indexing

I need to improve the time of one fetch request to coredata, so I was thinking in indexing some attributes.
My doubt is, I will insert the rows manually in the sqlite file with sql, so will the indexing of the attributes have any effect? Or I need to insert the data by code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bad Idea. The database isn't yours to insert data into. The Core Data framework does not expect its data to change underneath it, and you will almost certainly get unusual/unexpected results.

If Core Data doesn't perform well enough for you ([and it may not, as described here](http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data)), then you should consider just using SQLite directly, and managing your own database.

Comment: I create the database and sqlite file with coredata, then i just insert some data, because de app is supost to show that data, and it works great, I just want to improve the performance

Comment: If you're not inserting the data with Core Data, then that's unsupported, and you can't be sure what will happen.